# Grammar for "All systems were go."

Tags: word-meaning

> He adjusted his AKG headphones and checked the input levels on the hard-disk recording system. ***All systems were go***. ......

> "The Da Vinci Code"

I don't understand the grammar of the sentence. Is 'go' here a noun or verb?

Comment: It's an adjective and means all systems were *functioning properly* [Lexico].

Comment: It's a cliché from the early years of space travel, not standard English.  https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/all-systems-go.html

Comment: The opposite was, I believe, 'no-go'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In (mainly US) military, engineering, etc, circles, a process or operation may be preceded by a 'pass/fail' test to check whether all requirements are met. The 'pass' result may be called 'go' and the 'fail' result may be called 'no-go'.

[Go no-go (Wikipedia Engineering)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go/no_go#Engineering)

[Go-no-go (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-no-go)

Comment: There is also the concept of a "go/no-go" *tool* used in manufacturing, for example a tapered dowel used to check the size of a hole: the hole must be large enough that the "go" end can enter but small enough that the "no-go" end cannot.

Comment: There was the member of the Mothers of Invention (a 1970s rock group) nicknamed Roy "Walk/Don't walk" Estrada on a 1968 album cover. Now serving a long jail sentence.